# Is the product of two locally soluble groups is locally soluble?

Tags: group-theory

> A group $G$ is locally soluble if all finitely generated subgroups are soluble.

My question is the class of locally soluble group is it $N_0$-closed?If it is no is there contre example?and what class of group the property is true.

Comment: What do you mean by the product of two groups? If you mean the direct product, then the answer is yes, and the proof is easy.

Comment: closed under taking finite normal product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of locally soluble group is not  $N_0$-closed. P.Hall has given an (unpublished) example described in Part 2 of Robinson's "Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups". Theorem 8.19.1 on page 91.